# How to fix brightness on Ubuntu 14-04 LTS installed on macbook pro 2012 13"

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, brightness, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.02 as dual boot in a **macbook pro 2012 13**  I noticed that all function buttons works but except those that regulate the brightness of the screen.How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126441/brightness-controls-doesnt-work-on-a-macbook-pro-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts http://askubuntu.com/questions/370857/cant-adjust-screen-brightness-on-macbook-pro-10-1-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: My macbook has not nvidia graphic card, so probably nvidia drivers doesn't fix the problem in this case

Comment: BTW, can you change the brightness using the command line?

Comment: I was reading this post [link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop/57610#57610[link]. When I run `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`, my output is `/sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness`. 
`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`. Which one do I use? apple_backlight or intel_backlight?

Comment: Ok, I can change the brightness using command line but is there another method?

Comment: That was just a test, so we know, that only the control buttons are not working.

Comment: Could you add the `Xorg.conf` file to the question? BTW check this out: http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to this. However I have an iMac 2011, so it could solve your problem.

You need to edit the grub file `/etc/default/grub` change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Rebooot your computer and voilà.